# Bigquery Java API - get table creation time?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Is there a way to get the table creation time using the Bigquery Java Api? Currently I see that you can only fetch datasetid, projectid and tableid.

My usecase: I have a program that creates a table on a daily basis. Sometimes this program is run more than once a day. I wanted to add a check to see if the table was already created for this date and if so - ignore recreating it. For various other reasons, I cannot append the creation time to the tableid.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use the [creationTime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get#try-it) field returned by the API. The [Java library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/) already holds function for [getCreationTime()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/Table.html#getCreationTime());
2. You can use meta queries for that:

Run `SELECT * FROM <dataset>.__TABLES_SUMMARY__` to get all meta information about table.

The `__TABLES__` portion of that query may look unfamiliar. `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` is a meta-table containing information about tables in a dataset. You can use this meta-table yourself. For example, the query `SELECT * FROM publicdata:samples.__TABLES_SUMMARY__` will return metadata about the tables in the `publicdata:samples` dataset.

**Available Fields:**

The fields of the `__TABLES_SUMMARY__` meta-table (that are all available in the `TABLE_QUERY` query) include:

- `table_id`: name of the table.
- `creation_time`: time, in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC, that the table was created. This is the same as the `creation_time` field on the table.
- `type`: whether it is a view (2) or regular table (1).

The following fields are *not* available in `TABLE_QUERY()` since they are members of `__TABLES__` but not `__TABLES_SUMMARY__`. They're kept here for historical interest and to partially document the `__TABLES__` metatable:

- `last_modified_time`: time, in milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC, that the table was updated (either metadata or table contents). Note that if you use the `tabledata.insertAll()` to stream records to your table, this might be a few minutes out of date.
- `row_count`: number of rows in the table.
- `size_bytes`: total size in bytes of the table.

Comment: No offense, but that is not really practical solution. I have to run the query, parse the result to get a simple field. Wish we could simply do something like: table.getCreationTIme() just as we have table.getTableId()

Comment: @FebianShah The API already returns creationTime when you do a GET table call. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/get#try-it

Comment: @FebianShah Java library also has the getCreationTime function call: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/ full link: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/Table.html#getCreationTime()